# Aftet CMOS reset pc turns on but no display and 20sec later sound a bip then restart

Tags: bios, motherboard

Today I tried to get into the bios on a old desktop computer that I try to repair, but when I tried to enter the bios it doesn't appear any display, then it starts windows automatically so watching some info I found a solution that if I tried removing the cmos for 10 seconds and then put it back it will solve the problem and I will be able to access the bios.
But now when I turn it on there is nothing on the display and some seconds later it sound a beep before it restart again repeating the same thing as described, please help me I don't know why this happened.
)PC HP ProDesk 600 G2

Comment: Try replacing the battery with a new one.